# Different results from pickle file for sklearn classification models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, pickle, plotly-dash

I am creating a dashboard with dash,  for a sklearn classification models.
I want to plot roc curve and some indicators to evaluate the model([like is shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGvzk.png)).

the problem is dash doesn't allowed more then one output, so I have two solutions:

- I generate the model again (and this will cost a lot of time)
- or just use pickle to save sklearn generated model.
  but when i load the pickled model, the results are different like it is shown in the image, for example : the original AUC(Area Under the curve)=0.7 and from picked  file =0.93. I tries to do the same with joblib but same problem.

Pardon me this is a sample of the code, because it is very long:

```
    @app.callback(Output('modelReport', 'rows'),
                  [Input('report', 'n_clicks'),
                  Input('model', 'value'),])
    def modelClassifierReport (button, mod): 
        if (button ==None):
            return [{}]
        else:
 ## saving and generating models ###   
            if (mod == 'logreg'):
                Title='Logistic regression'
                logreg = LogisticRegression()
                logreg.fit(x_train,y_train)
                model=logreg
                with open("python_logreg_model.pkl", "wb") as file_handler:
                    pickle.dump(logreg, file_handler)

            elif (mod =='mlp' ):
                mlp=MLPClassifier()
                mlp=mlp.fit(x_train, y_train)
                with open("python_mlp_model.pkl", "wb") as file_handler:
                    pickle.dump(mlp, file_handler)
                model=mlp
            elif :
                .......#other models#

            ####------------###
            #### comput indicator to evaluate models ####
            ####------------###

            report=pd.DataFrame({'creteria':['Accuracy','erreur I','erreurII' ,'AUC','CV ACU','AIC','som error']})
            report['Value']=[model_score,fnr,fpr,AUC, cv_mean,AIC,RSS]
            return  report.to_dict('records')
    #####################
    @app.callback(Output('my-graph', 'figure'),
                  [Input ('roc','n_clicks'),])

    def RocPlot (button):
        if (button ==None):
            return [{}]
        else:
### loading models 
            if(mod == 'logreg'):
                with open("python_logreg_model.pkl", "rb") as file_handler:
                    model = pickle.load(file_handler)
            elif (mod=='mlp' ):
                with open("python_mlp_model.pkl", "rb") as file_handler:
                    model = pickle.load(file_handler)
            #### load other models ####
            ####------------###
            ####------------###
            fp, tp, threshold= metrics.roc_curve(y_test, model.predict_proba(x_test)[:,1])
            AUC= metrics.auc(fp, tp)
            lw = 2
            trace1 = go.Scatter(x=fp, y=tp, 
                                mode='lines', 
                                line=dict(color='darkorange', width=lw),
                                name='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % AUC )
            trace2 = go.Scatter(x=[0, 1], y=[0, 1], 
                                mode='lines', 
                                line=dict(color='navy', width=lw, dash='dash'),
                                showlegend=False)
            layout = go.Layout(title='Receiver operating characteristic example',
                                xaxis=dict(title='False Positive Rate'),
                                yaxis=dict(title='True Positive Rate'))
            print('plot done')
            return{ 'data': [trace1, trace2], 'layout': layout }
```

how can i solve this issue with the pickled models? is  there other way to save sklearn models? any suggestion?

Comment: Please also show how you are processing the data? How did you make the X_train and X_test, etc?

Comment: Thx a lot  for your response !  the dataset is uploaded by the user of the app,`df =pd.DataFrame(tablerows)         y=df[yvar]
        y=np.ravel(y)   x=df[Features] x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size =float(ech) ,  stratify=y)` , `yvar` is columns  name  of the dependent feature  selected by the user and `Features` is list of explicative feature and also selected by the user.